# LINQ for string StartsWith some value in List<string>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm parsing an XDocument using LINQ. I want to check if one of the XElements, with key "BusinessStructure" *starts with* one of the strings in my `List<string> filters`. In other words, let's say I have:

`x.Element("BusinessStructure").Value = "testing123"`

and

`var filters = new List<string> {"test", "hello"}`

Using LINQ, how do I then do something like...

```
...
where x.Element("BusinessStructure").Value.StartsWith(filters[0])
select new...
```

But instead of getting the first index of the filters list, I want to "loop" through all the values in the list and check if the XElement value starts with it. Is this possible using LINQ or do I have to do it using a `foreach`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do a straight LINQ solution, modifying your query slightly:

```
let bs = x.Element("BusinessStructure")
where bs != null && filters.Any(f => bs.Value.StartsWith(f))
```

Or you could build a regex from your filters:

```
var prefixRegex = new Regex("\\A" + string.Join("|",filters.Select(f=>Regex.Escape(f)));
...
let bs = x.Element("BusinessStructure")
where bs != null && prefixRegex.IsMatch(bs.Value)
```

If performance is a consideration, try and measure both.

Comment: Note that if that element is not there you'll get a NRE.  Better to explicitly cast to string and check that - `where filters.Any(f => ((string)x.Element("BusinessStructure")).StartsWith(f));`

Comment: @Tim thanks for alerting me to NRE possibility.  I'd rather deal with that using an explicit null check to make the intent a little clearer.  Edited.

Answer (score -2):

I would do something like that;

```
filters.Any(f => x.Element("BusinessStructure").Value.IndexOf(f)==0)
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile. And if corrected it is basically the same (without the error checking) as the current accepted answer.

Comment: What are you talking about? I am using this code, it compiles well. it just needs to be put in the loop. I just put here the code which makes the checking task. You have a point in that it is a little like the accepted answer, but it is not the same. You should find something better to do here

Comment: `CS0119 'XContainer.Element(XName)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context`. I am doing exactly what I should here. The community's job is to improve the quality of all questions and answers.

Comment: OMG, that is getting funny. I edited the code so it gets compiled. Be happy!